# Unresolved reference: getSensorList in SensorManager.getSensorList

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am writing a simple code to find out all available sensors in an Android System.
I don't know why I am getting this error. Neither Android docs have mentioned any exception as such that may occur nor I think I am doing any mistake in writing code.

```
var sensorList = SensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)
```

This `getSensorList()` method is giving me error. What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate what's exactly the problem with that code. Maybe you could provide a stacktrace as well to add more information about the error.

Comment: I am getting a compile time error saying Unresolved reference: getSensorList. That's it. The above line of code is the only line of code I am having tin program

Comment: Make sure that you have the following imports in your code:
`import android.hardware.Sensor;`
`import android.hardware.SensorManager;`